# pyspark : Extra first non-null value from a comma delimited string in a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, extract

I have a Dataframe with two columns id and phone number in the below format

```
id | phone_number  
 1 | ,1234567890,,0987654321,  
 2 |,7890123456,,9078651243,
```

I want to split the phone_number column and pick just the first non-empty value in a separate column in pyspark

Resultant dataframe should be

```
id | phone_number               | extracted_phone  
 1 | ,1234567890,,0987654321,   |1234567890  
 2 |,,,9078651243,              |9078651243
```

Comment: remove the leading spaces and commas using `regexp_replace()`, split by comma ',' and then take the first element of the split result. `df.withColumn('extracted_phone', F.split(F.regexp_replace('phone_number ', r'^[,\s]+', ''), ',')[0])`

Comment: Thanks. This works